# OpenVPN configuration - connection but I can't route or ping

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have OpenVPN installed on a firewall server, sitting in front of a private network.  I can connect, and I see the connection appearing in the openvpn logs, but I am unable to ping or load anything from any server on the internal network.

If I attempt to ping an intranet server by IP address I get the message `Reply from 10.128.101.10: Destination net unreachable`, and if I attempt to ping anything by name I get `Ping request could not find host... etc`.  The request never shows up in the openvpn logs, so it does not appear to be getting routed through the VPN, and I'm also not sure where the response from 10.128.101.10 is coming from.

If I ping an external IP on the client it succeeds, but again there is no record of it happening on the openvpn server logs, so it appears the client is not routing calls to the internet through the VPN connection either.

The configuration of interfaces on the server:

```
br0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:69:95:5b:8d:ec  
      inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::e269:95ff:fe5b:8dec/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:9035476320 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11368163767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1425939281018 (1.2 TiB)  TX bytes:14626327838608 (13.3 TiB)

eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e0:69:95:5b:8d:ec  
      inet6 addr: fe80::e269:95ff:fe5b:8dec/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:11674359651 errors:34 dropped:1328386 overruns:34 frame:19926134
      TX packets:11373312670 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:3043072932401 (2.7 TiB)  TX bytes:14626883362068 (13.3 TiB)

eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:b5:5b:08  
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:feb5:5b08/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:12270417886 errors:37631 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:37631
      TX packets:9127804244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:15633780809274 (14.2 TiB)  TX bytes:1623523556910 (1.4 TiB)
      Interrupt:18 Memory:fbee0000-fbf00000 

eth2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:b5:59:03  
      inet addr:192.168.3.1  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:feb5:5903/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1320860615 errors:666 dropped:5304850 overruns:0 frame:666
      TX packets:1292682318 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:107393626703 (100.0 GiB)  TX bytes:163948085261 (152.6 GiB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:fbfe0000-fc000000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1152727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1152727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:114734660 (109.4 MiB)  TX bytes:114734660 (109.4 MiB)

tap0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:92:54:10:ea:1a  
      inet addr:10.8.0.1  Bcast:10.8.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::fc92:54ff:fe10:ea1a/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1020 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
      RX bytes:241766 (236.0 KiB)  TX bytes:29025 (28.3 KiB)

vlan3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:b5:5b:08  
      inet addr:192.168.2.20  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::21b:21ff:feb5:5b08/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1625308557 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1236994877 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1651579269402 (1.5 TiB)  TX bytes:318808317936 (296.9 GiB)

vlan4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1b:21:b5:5b:08  
      inet addr:{EXTERNAL IP}  Bcast:{EXTERNAL IP}  Mask:255.255.255.252
      inet6 addr: {EXTERNAL INET6} Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:10503666500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:7853875214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:13705059452296 (12.4 TiB)  TX bytes:1228228471170 (1.1 TiB)
```

The server.conf file...

```
mode server
tls-server

local EXTERNAL-IP-OF-OPENVPN
port 1194

proto udp

dev tap0

script-security 2

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem

topology subnet

server-bridge 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.200 192.168.0.255
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "route-gateway 192.168.0.5"

push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.5"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN x.mycompany.com"

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0

cipher AES-128-CBC

comp-lzo yes

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
verb 4

passtos
```

The client .ovpn configuration file:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote EXTERNAL-IP-OF-OPENVPN 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
mute-replay-warnings
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo yes
verb 3
;mute 20

ca [inline]
cert [inline]
key [inline]
tls-auth [inline] 1

{CERTIFICATES LOCATED BELOW THIS LINE}
```

The interfaces on the client:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::20c4:bf26:637:4ac%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : x.mycompany.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::797d:baa3:b046:8068%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.200
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::480b:cfa9:763b:a4fb%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.107
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Logs from server on start:

```
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365838   ssl_flags = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365849   tls_timeout = 2
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365861   renegotiate_bytes = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365872   renegotiate_packets = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365883   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365895   handshake_window = 60
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365910   transition_window = 3600
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365922   single_session = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365934   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365945   tls_exit = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=365956   tls_auth_file = 'ta.key'

Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366567   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366579   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366591   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366605   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366623   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366638   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366650   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366663   server_bridge_ip = 192.168.0.1
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366677   server_bridge_netmask = 255.255.255.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366693   server_bridge_pool_start = 192.168.0.200
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366706   server_bridge_pool_end = 192.168.0.255
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366718   push_entry = 'redirect-gateway def1'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366729   push_entry = 'route-gateway 192.168.0.5'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366741   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.5'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366753   push_entry = 'dhcp-option DOMAIN x.mycompany.com'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366767   push_entry = 'route-gateway 192.168.0.1'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366779   push_entry = 'ping 10'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366790   push_entry = 'ping-restart 120'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366802   ifconfig_pool_defined = ENABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366815   ifconfig_pool_start = 192.168.0.200
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366828   ifconfig_pool_end = 192.168.0.255
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366841   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 255.255.255.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366853   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366867   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366879   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366891   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366903   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366914   n_bcast_buf = 256
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366927   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366940   real_hash_size = 256
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366952   virtual_hash_size = 256
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366963   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366975   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=366997   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367012   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367024   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367036   tmp_dir = '/tmp'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367047   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367060   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367074   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367088   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367101   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367114   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367125   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367137   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367148   cf_max = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367162   cf_per = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367174   max_clients = 1024
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367185   max_routes_per_client = 256
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367197   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367208   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367220   port_share_host = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367232   port_share_port = 0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367243   client = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367255   pull = DISABLED
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367270   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367284 OpenVPN 2.3.4 i586-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367304 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015, LZO 2.08
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=367461 NOTE: when bridging your LAN adapter with the TAP adapter, note that the new bridge adapter will often take on its own IP address that is different from what the LAN adapter was previously set to
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=371942 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 1024 bit key
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372407 Control Channel Authentication: using 'ta.key' as a OpenVPN static key file
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372426 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372437 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372451 TLS-Auth MTU parms [ L:1590 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372473 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=372961 TUN/TAP device tap0 opened
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=373006 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=373041 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1590 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=374068 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]PUBLIC_IP_OF_OPENVPN:1194
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=374284 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=374372 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=374574 IFCONFIG POOL: base=192.168.0.200 size=56, ipv6=0
Tue Mar 27 15:53:33 2018 us=374722 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

The server logs after client connection:

```
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301210 MULTI: multi_create_instance called
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301383 24.114.89.0:62331 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301436 24.114.89.0:62331 LZO compression initialized
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301696 24.114.89.0:62331 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1590 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301742 24.114.89.0:62331 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1590 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:32 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301807 24.114.89.0:62331 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 0,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-server'
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301831 24.114.89.0:62331 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1590,tun-mtu 1532,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,keydir 1,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,tls-auth,key-method 2,tls-client'
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301880 24.114.89.0:62331 Local Options hash (VER=V4): 'c5677ab3'
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=301937 24.114.89.0:62331 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'a7133b47'
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=302010 24.114.89.0:62331 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]24.114.89.0:62331, sid=285877f0 58d30489
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=897948 24.114.89.0:62331 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=CA, ST=QC, L=Mycity, O=My Company, CN=My Company, emailAddress=spang@mycompany.com
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=898941 24.114.89.0:62331 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=CA, ST=QC, L=Mycity, O=My Company, OU=IT, CN=myname, name=My Name, emailAddress=myname@mycompany.com
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=990142 24.114.89.0:62331 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=990242 24.114.89.0:62331 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=990334 24.114.89.0:62331 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Mar 27 15:57:59 2018 us=990368 24.114.89.0:62331 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 us=67010 24.114.89.0:62331 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 us=67140 24.114.89.0:62331 [myname] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]24.114.89.0:62331
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 us=67759 MULTI: new connection by client 'myname' will cause previous active sessions by this client to be dropped.  Remember to use the --duplicate-cn option if you want multiple clients using the same certificate or username to concurrently connect.
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 us=67820 MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=192.168.0.200, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Tue Mar 27 15:58:01 2018 us=217750 myname/24.114.89.0:62331 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Tue Mar 27 15:58:01 2018 us=217847 myname/24.114.89.0:62331 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Tue Mar 27 15:58:01 2018 us=217965 myname/24.114.89.0:62331 SENT CONTROL [myname]: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 192.168.0.5,dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.5,dhcp-option DOMAIN x.mycompany.com,route-gateway 192.168.0.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 192.168.0.200 255.255.255.0' (status=1)
Tue Mar 27 15:58:01 2018 us=348186 myname/24.114.89.0:62331 MULTI: Learn: 00:ff:82:8f:2e:c3 -> myname/24.114.89.0:62331
```

Log messages on client side:

```
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 192.168.0.5,dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.5,dhcp-option DOMAIN x.mycompany.com,route-gateway 192.168.0.1,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 192.168.0.200 255.255.255.0'
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Incoming Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 interactive service msg_channel=584
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.43.1/255.255.255.0 I=13 HWADDR=9c:b6:d0:dd:62:37
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 open_tun
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \\.\Global\{828F2EC3-A0BB-4461-8535-888844B3A50E}.tap
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 192.168.0.200/255.255.255.0 on interface {828F2EC3-A0BB-4461-8535-888844B3A50E} [DHCP-serv: 192.168.0.0, lease-time: 31536000]
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 Successful ARP Flush on interface [9] {828F2EC3-A0BB-4461-8535-888844B3A50E}
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Mar 27 15:58:00 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1522180680,ASSIGN_IP,,192.168.0.200,,,,
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD PUBLIC_IP MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.43.1
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 C:\WINDOWS\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Mar 27 15:58:05 2018 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1522180685,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,192.168.0.200,PUBLIC_IP_OFOPENVPN,1194,,
```